# Save the date given from datepicker java

Tags: java, datepicker

I am trying to use the datepicker class in java. I have a datepicker created. What I want to be able to do is have a button that, when clicked, will save the date as a date object so that I can access it later and manipulate the date(like calculate two days from the selected date). I am stuck on how to begin. Can anyone give me any starting points?

Comment: what `datepicker` class are you talking about?

Comment: Save it if the program is closed or for later in the program?

Comment: the datepicker in javafx

Answer (score 0):

As per the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html)

```
final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
 datePicker.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
     public void handle(Event t) {
         LocalDate date = datePicker.getValue();
         System.err.println("Selected date: " + date);
     }
 });
```

If you want to use the `Date` outside of this method, the have the `LocalDate` Object as a field

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I'll try this.

Comment: What do you mean by have the Date Object as a field?

Comment: Sorry I meant `LocalDate date` as a field not as a local variable.

Comment: So, put LocalDate date outside of the handle class?

Comment: Yes, the `EventHandler` is in another class right?  Make the `date` a field of the containing class.